# How to alert current index

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to `alert(index)` if I click the current `<p>`

```js
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <script>
       $("p").click(function(){
          for(i=0;i<$(this).length;i++) {
              if($(this).eq(i).data("clicked",true))
                  {
                      alert(i);
                  }
          }
         }) 
    </script>
```

I tried this code but it shows `0` whatever I click.
I would like to see current index with alert.For ex. when i will click second `<p>`, it should show 1.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do exactly, but would `alert($(this).index());` not work?

Comment: Post your HTML too please. We need a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your original code, you were setting the upper bound of your loop like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < $(this).length; i++)
```

`this` is going to refer to just the one element you clicked on, so `$(this).length` is always going to be `1`, which always has an index of `0`.

Additionally, your test was:

```
if($(this).eq(i).data("clicked", "true"))
```

This syntax sets the data property `clicked` to `true` (not tests to see if the value is `true`). As such, it will always succeed, which is why you always got taken to the `true` branch of your `if` statement and then always got `0`.

To test the property, you should write:

```
if($(this).eq(i).data("clicked") === "true")
```

A much simpler implementation is to use `index()`. See **[this](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/understanding-index/)** for details on `index()`. Here's a complete version that alerts you as to whether you are clicking an element for the first time or not. No looping or the use of `eq()` (which gets you an element at a specified index and not the index itself) is required.

```js
$("p").click(function(){
  // Get the index position of the currently clicked element, within the set of <p> elements
  var idx = $(this).index("p");
  
  // Test to see if the element has already been clicked.
  if($(this).data("clicked") === "true"){
    alert("Element " + idx + " has already been clicked.");
  } else {
    alert("You just clicked element " + idx + " for the first time.");
  }

  // Mark the element as clicked for next time:
  $(this).data("clicked", "true");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
```

Comment: can i use for , and eq() ?and why it shows 1 not 0.

Comment: @Arman See my updated answer, which produces a 0-based result. You could use a `for` loop and, if you did, you wouldn't need `eq` at all. But, why would you want to do that when `index()` solves the problem?

Comment: @Arman, no ` .eq() ` is in fact for selecting element on provided index. And reason why it shows 1 when you click on ` <p>1</p> ` is the fact, the ` .index() ` returns index of selected item in context of it's parent. If you want to get index from list of exact elements, wrap them in separate element.

Comment: @Scott Marcus thanks.I want to know what i did wrong. am i use eq() right? if yes , what i did wrong in my code?

Comment: @Arman no, actually you haven't. In fact, you made two mistakes. First is, `$(this)` refers in context of clicked event - the element event got fired into. So, you tried to find element of some index on that, exact element. You should get it's parent and it's children first, or to get it's sibling list. Second problem is, you said, you want to get just an index. If you want to use index - use `.index()` function. If you want to get element on such index, use `.eq()`, but first you need to get list of elements, to grab the index from.

Comment: @Scott Marcus thanks, one last question , but anyway can i use for like that?            for(i=0;i<$("p").length;i++){
           
            }